# using logical and in unix shell script for switch case

Tags: shell, unix, switch-statement, logical-operators

Is it possible to use a logical AND in a unix shell script switch case. If so, how?

```
switch $var in
    1 AND $var2 EQUALS 2)
        some code
```

Comment: Use an `if` in the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `if` statements for that.

See [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html).

> "Each case is an expression matching a pattern. The commands in the
>   COMMAND-LIST for the first match are executed. The "|" symbol is used
>   for separating multiple patterns, and the ")" operator terminates a
>   pattern list. "

So you need to have patterns, not an expression to be evaluated, for each case.

Comment: @nazco: Of course there are ways to do it with `case`; they may not be as sensible as the `if`, but...see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
case "$var1:$var2" in
(1:2) # $var1 = 1 && $var2 == 2
      ;;
...
esac
```

In this case, I added the colon (an arbitrary non-digit) so you can be reasonably sure that the values are as stated.  However, if someone achieved `var1="1:2"` and `var2=""`, then the test would pass but the values would not be as required.  If, however, you're in charge of the variables, this can be perfectly sensible.  It is probably cleaner to use `if` for simple value tests, but if you needed range tests, this could be more succinct than the equivalent `if` without being much less clear:

```
case "$var1:$var2" in
([1-3]:[4-9]) # $var1 in {1,2,3} && $var2 in {4,5,6,7,8,9}
      ;;
...
esac

case "$var1:$var2" in
(*amber*:*gold*) # $var1 contains 'amber' && $var2 contains 'gold'
      ;;
...
esac
```

It's likely that `bash` has the built-in capabilities to handle even the latter; older shells did not.  This technique might be useful if you need to port to machines with `bash` installed by default (perhaps AIX, HP-UX, Solaris).

Comment: finally helpful after 7 years!